# Why does Angular HttpClient replace "\n" with "↵"

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

Sending a POST body with the HttpClient that either is a string or is an object that has a string as a value will replace any occurrence of "\n" with "↵". This is primarily happening in Chrome 73. In firefox, it seems that "↵" appears as " " when viewing the Network call in the Inspector.

I've tried using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse and replacing "↵" with "\n" to no avail.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzxank

I expect the POST request body found shown in the browser's inspector to use "\n" and not "↵".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not particular to Angular's HTTP Client. That's merely how Chrome formats the display of line breaks within strings.

Check the demo below.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = () => 
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'title',
      body: 'foo\nbar',
      userId: 1
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

```html
Open Dev Tools. Then click:<br>
<button>click me</button><br>
Now check the HTTP call (the one with 201) in the networks tab<br>
Notice the line break is still shown as "↵" in Chrome.<br>
Notice also that the "\n" is properly transmitted, as shown by the response object's "body" field.
```